# Why can I save an enum to Firestore, but it crashes the app when I try to retrieve the same?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, enums

I have the following defined:

```
enum class Venues (val nickname: String) {
    Venue1 ("Venue 1"),
    Venue2 ("Venue 2")
}

data class Tournament (var aString: String = "Title",
                       var aDate: Date = Date(),
                       var anInt: Int = 8,
                       var venue: Venues = Venues.Venue1,
                       var aBoolean: Boolean = true)
```

The following code to write a `Tournament` to Firestore works as expected:

```
fun createNewTournament(view: View) {
    val teamCount = (8..24).random()
    val venue: Venues = Venues.values().random()

    val newTournament = Tournament("String", Date(), teamCount, venue, false)

    tournamentsRef.add(newTournament)
        .addOnSuccessListener { docRef -> Log.d ("ADD", "DocSnapShot has id: ${docRef.id}") }
        .addOnFailureListener {      e -> Log.w ("ADD", "Error adding document", e)}
}
```

Looking in the Firebase console, I see a complete `Tournament` document with a `venue` field defined as a `String`.

However, my app crashes on the `toObjects` line when I try to read the same:

```
val tournamentsRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("tournaments")
var tournaments = ArrayList<Tournament>()

tournamentsRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error ->
    if (error != null) {
        return@addSnapshotListener
    }

    // CRASH: this line crashes if enum is included
    tournaments = snapshot!!.toObjects(Tournament::class.java) as ArrayList<Tournament>
}
```

If I remove the `venue` enum from the `data class`, all of the documents are read successfully, but obviously without the `venue` field.

So, how does one use `enum`s with Firestore, specifically, how do I convert the incoming `String` to my `enum`?

For comparison's sake, here's the Swift code I'm using in the iOS version of this app:

```
enum Venues: String, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case venue1 = "Venue 1"
    case venue2 = "Venue 2"
}

struct Tournament: Codable {
    var aString: String
    var aDate: Date
    var anInt: Int
    var venue: Venues
    var aBoolean: Bool
}

let tournamentsRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("tournaments")
var tournaments = [Tournament]()

tournamentsRef
    .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else { return }

        self.tournaments = documents.compactMap { document in
            let tournament = try? document.data(as: Tournament.self)
            return tournament
        }
    }

func createNewTournament() {
    let newTournament = Tournament(aString: "String", aDate: Date(), anInt: 8, venue: Venues.venue1, aBoolean: true)

    do {
        let _ = try tournamentsRef.addDocument(from: newTournament)
    } catch {
        print (error)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact exception which is thrown? How are the enums saved in Firebase using 1. Android and 2. iOS? Is it `Venue1`, is it `Venue 1`, is it something else? I'd guess Android has some difficulty to map the firebase value to an enum. `val nickname` is not automatically used when saving and `Venues("Venue 2")` does not automatically become `Venue2`

Comment: My first hunch would be you to make the enum exten `Serializable` or `Parcelable`

Comment: Hi, good questions. I tried some options. In iOS, as written, FS gets "Venue 1". If I remove the strings, then it saves "venue1". In Android, FS gets the enum value, regardless of the nickname. In fact, I should remove the nickname part, as it's not relevant. But, if I keep the enum value in Kotlin the same as the associated strings in Swift, that keeps them consistent.... lemme try....

Comment: OK, that was quick. Android version still crashing on the same line. Now I have to research Serializable/Parcelable.

Comment: Error message: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Could not find enum value of com.heewhack.enumtest.TournamentVenues for value "Venue2" (found in field 'venue')

So, clearly, you're idea is on the right path. I added ":Serializable" to the code, but that didn't seem to help.....

Comment: What if you add `: Parcelable`, annotate it with `@Parcelize` and first try to open a document which is saved by Android?

Comment: It worked. I added support and then added @Serializable before my enum and now it's working. Thank you! If you submit as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize, `snapshot.toObjects()` cannot deserialize non-primitives out of the box.

By annotating the enum with `@Parcelize` or `@Serializable`, this will generate code under the hood so it knows how to do this for your custom class. Both need a gradle dependency, `org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize` and `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization` respectively.

For an enum such as:

```
enum class Venues (val nickname: String) {
    Venue1 ("Venue 1"),
    Venue2 ("Venue 2")
}
```

`nickname` is not used, if not defined specifically. `Venue1` will be serialized as such, `Venue1`.